# Reload page without affecting YouTube progress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, youtube

I'm working on making a semi-live streamed internet channel using PHP, HTML & JavaScript.

You can see a demo here: http://mariocreative.host/chanelko/index.php

Now I have a very big problem :(

I'm using

```
if( (date('h:i:a') >= 12:00:00) && (date('h:i:a') < 12:00:01) ){
    $youtubevideoid='O__TkxSdkLk';
    $youtubevideostart='1';
}
if( (date('h:i:a') >= 12:00:00) && (date('h:i:a') < 12:00:02) ){
    $youtubevideoid='O__TkxSdkLk';
    $youtubevideostart='2';
}
if( (date('h:i:a') >= 12:00:00) && (date('h:i:a') < 12:00:03) ){
    $youtubevideoid='O__TkxSdkLk';
    $youtubevideostart='3';
}
```

Right now to start this video from 12:00:00 PM until 12:01:40 PM , but to continue on the above method this will take like 2 hours !! :/

Also, I'm refreshing the page with the AJAX method using this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                    $('#show').text(
                            ' '
                                    + randomnumber);
                }, 5000);
            });
</script>
```

Which will refresh the page every 5 seconds.

And the code which is used to display the YouTube video is:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="900px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $youtubevideoid; ?>?&autoplay=1&rel=0&theme=light&start=<?php echo $youtubevideostart; ?>&showinfo=0&controls=0&hd=1&autohide=1&color=white" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Can you please tell me how to refresh the page without affecting the played YouTube progress using JavaScript ?**

Thanks :)

Comment: Don't refresh the page, use the AJAX to re-write the DOM with the new data that is needed from the server.

Comment: @chris85 - I must refresh because more than 1 video will be uploaded to this live streaming, and not only 1.

Comment: as for the first question, have you tried just one `&& (date('h:i:a') < 12:01:40)` and calculate `$youtubevideostart` as a difference between the 2 time points (now and 12:00:00)?

Comment: How many $youtubevideostart numbers are there? - one for every second in the day?

Comment: @YakovL - I can't do that, because we can't do that on the YouTube Embed.

Comment: Why, you can create `iframe` dynamically as well, can't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found ANSWER (This answer was posted for the people who faced the same problem):

The video which I want to play is 1 minute and 40 seconds.

Firstly, I will run it for 1 minute and 25 seconds to bring some advertisements then I will run the rest of the video.

So here is the code:

```
if( (date('H:i:s') >= 12:00:00) && (date('H:i:s') < 12:01:25) ){
    $youtubevideoid='O__TkxSdkLk';
    $youtubevideostart='0';
    $youtubevideoend='85';
}
```

While the iframe code must be replaced with:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $youtubevideoid; ?>?&autoplay=1&rel=0&theme=light&start=<?php echo $youtubevideostart; ?>&end=<?php echo $youtubevideoend; ?>&showinfo=0&controls=0&hd=1&autohide=1&color=white" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

EDIT: Only 15 seconds will be remaining if we used 1:25 from 1:40 - so we will complete them after the advertisements.

Last code:

```
if( (date('H:i:s') >= 12:00:00) && (date('H:i:s') < 12:01:25) ){
    $youtubevideoid='O__TkxSdkLk';
    $youtubevideostart='0';
    $youtubevideoend='85';
}
//advertisement youtube video
if( (date('H:i:s') >= 12:01:25) && (date('H:i:s') < 12:01:40) ){
    $youtubevideoid='O__TkxSdkLk';
    $youtubevideostart='85';
    $youtubevideoend='100';
}
```

**My problem was:** I didn't knew that's we can define an end to the YouTube video.